# Stored procedure has performance issue in updating table from source view

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql

Source_View has only close to 800 records only but my procedure taking almost 3 minutes to update the PHONE table. I have comments at each step to explain the logic. Any help is appreciated.

Requirement : Create a process to check the  phone numbers on a daily basis using  view and update it accordingly.

1) Get all territory keycol from Table 1 
SELCT * FROM Table1 WHERE CATEGORY = 'T';

2) get active sales rep data from table2 and get his user id
SELECT USER_ID FROM Table2 WHERE key_colval = '' AND JOB_TITLE = 'Sales Rep' AND STATUS = 'Active';

3) Use that user id to query source_VIEW
SELECT * FROM source_VIEW WHERE USER_ID = '' AND key_colval = '';

4) If we do not find anything from above step then
4.1) SELECT * FROM source_VIEW WHERE key_colval = '';

```
PROCEDURE main_PHONE_UPD 

IS

   V_USER_ID                      VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TMP_source_VIEW';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TMP_source_VIEW  SELECT SUBSTR(key_col,6) key_colval,MOBILE,USER_ID FROM  source_VIEW WHERE MOBILE IS NOT NULL'; -- Loading to temp table from source view 
    COMMIT;

   FOR REC IN (SELECT key_colval
                 FROM Table1
                WHERE CATEGORY = 'T' ) LOOP --- Getting only category 'T' from Table 1

      BEGIN
         SELECT USER_ID         -- Get user_id for given keycolval , getting only one value based on hire_date
           INTO V_USER_ID
           FROM(SELECT USER_ID
                  FROM Table2
                WHERE key_colval   = REC.key_colval
                  AND JOB_TITLE          = 'Sales Rep' 
                  AND STATUS = 'Active'
                  ORDER BY HIRE_DATE ASC)
          WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;          
         calling_PHONE_upd(V_USER_ID, REC.key_colval,'Y'); -- if data exists call this with indicator 'Y' to load phone table 
         COMMIT; 
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            calling_PHONE_upd(NULL, REC.key_colval,'N');  -- -- if data exists call this with indicator 'N' to load phone table 
            COMMIT;
      END;

   END LOOP;
END main_PHONE_UPD;


PROCEDURE calling_PHONE_upd( 

   IN_USER_ID                    VARCHAR2,
   IN_key_colval                 VARCHAR2,
   IN_USER_INDICATOR             VARCHAR2)
IS
    V_COUNT                 NUMBER := 0;
    V_PHONE_REC             PHONE%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN


   IF IN_USER_INDICATOR = 'Y' THEN
   FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM TMP_user_VIEW WHERE USER_ID=IN_USER_ID AND key_colval=IN_key_colval )
   LOOP  - This logic to update primary/secondary numbers if mutilple values 
      V_COUNT := V_COUNT + 1;
      V_PHONE_REC.key_colval  := rec.key_colval;
      V_PHONE_REC.PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE := CASE WHEN V_COUNT = 1 THEN 'PRI'
                                            WHEN V_COUNT = 2 THEN 'SCD'
                                            ELSE NULL
                                       END;
      V_PHONE_REC.PHONE_AREA_CODE   := SUBSTR(rec.MOBILE,1,3);
      V_PHONE_REC.PHONE_NUMBER      := SUBSTR(rec.MOBILE,5,3)||SUBSTR(rec.MOBILE,9);
      V_PHONE_REC.PHONE_EXTENSION   := NULL;
      BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO PHONE VALUES V_PHONE_REC;
      EXCEPTION
          WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
              BEGIN
                  UPDATE PHONE SET ROW = V_PHONE_REC WHERE key_colval = V_PHONE_REC.key_colval AND PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = V_PHONE_REC.PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE;
      END;
      IF V_COUNT > 2 THEN --Primary Phone Number
          EXIT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   ELSE

   FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM TMP_user_VIEW WHERE key_colval=IN_key_colval)
   LOOP  -- - This logic to update primary/secondary numbers if mutilple values 
      V_COUNT := V_COUNT + 1;
      V_PHONE_REC.PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE := CASE WHEN V_COUNT = 1 THEN 'PRI'
                                            WHEN V_COUNT = 2 THEN 'SCD'
                                            ELSE NULL
                                       END;
      V_PHONE_REC.PHONE_AREA_CODE   := SUBSTR(rec.MOBILE,1,3);
      V_PHONE_REC.PHONE_NUMBER      := SUBSTR(rec.MOBILE,5,3)||SUBSTR(rec.MOBILE,9);
      V_PHONE_REC.PHONE_EXTENSION   := NULL;
      BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO PHONE VALUES V_PHONE_REC;
      EXCEPTION
          WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
              BEGIN
                  UPDATE PHONE SET ROW = V_PHONE_REC WHERE key_colval = V_PHONE_REC.key_colval AND PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = V_PHONE_REC.PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE;
      END;
      IF V_COUNT > 2 THEN --Primary Phone Number
          EXIT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   END IF;

END calling_PHONE_upd;
```

Comment: use dbms_profiler to get the run time for each line of your stored procedure, do the same for calling_PHONE_upd, look at the execution plan for your SELECT in this procedure and of course the UPDATE statement in your calling_HOME_upd program

Comment: will check and see whether i can find any ...occupied with other stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you, I'd look to turn that into a single `MERGE` statement, something along the lines of:

```
MERGE INTO phone tgt
USING (SELECT t1.key_colval,
              t2.user_id,
              CASE WHEN t2.user_id IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END INDICATOR
              CASE WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.colval ORDER BY t1.colval) = 1 THEN 'PRI'
                   ELSE 'SCD'
              END phone_number_type,
              SUBSTR(tuv.MOBILE,1,3) PHONE_AREA_CODE,
              SUBSTR(tuv.MOBILE,5,3)||SUBSTR(tuv.MOBILE,9) PHONE_NUMBER,
              NULL PHONE_EXTENSION
       FROM   Table1 t1
              LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT key_colval,
                                      user_id
                               FROM   (SELECT user_id,
                                              key_colval,
                                              row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY key_colval ORDER BY hire_date DESC) rn
                                       FROM   table2
                                       WHERE  job_title = 'Sales Rep'
                                       AND    status = 'Active') t
                               WHERE  rn = 1) t2 ON t1.key_colval = t2.key_colval
              INNER JOIN tmp_user_view tuv ON tuv.key_colval = t1.key_colval AND ((t2.user_id IS NOT NULL AND tuv.user_id = t2.user_id) OR t2.user_id IS NULL)
       WHERE  t1.CATEGORY = 'T'
       AND    ROWNUM <= 2 -- there's no ordering mentioned in your calling_PHONE_upd cursors, so if there should be, you'd need another method of working out the correct 2 rows to return and in which order
       ) src
       ON (tgt.key_colval = src.key_colval -- plus additional columns that make the join between the tgt table and src subquery produce a 1-2-1 mapping
           )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.phone_number_type = src.phone_number_type -- add in the other columns (not the ones in the ON clause above!)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (tgt.key_colval, ...) -- list the other columns being inserted into
  VALUES (src.key_colval, ...); -- list the other source columns being inserted
```

I came up with this statement after going through your logic and turning the manual nested loop joins (cursor loops within cursor loops) into a single select statement, and then using that to do a merge, rather than insert-or-update statements.

That should improve things vastly, since you're now able to let the optimizer determine the best way of joining the tables, and you're cutting out all the context switching between SQL and PL/SQL.

I also wouldn't bother with staging tables; just use the query that populated the staging tables directly in the Merge statement's source subquery. That saves you time truncating and inserting data.

N.B. My statement is obviously untested, since you didn't provide a full test case with sample data and expected output. If it doesn't work as you expect, I would recommend you fix it for your case, rather than proceeding with the highly procedural code you have at present.

Comment: hopefully i will give a try and then will update you ...mostly here i need to strict with step by step process

Comment: you asked for help and @boneist went out of their way considering lack of information - you should def give it a shot

Comment: @boneist ... I just tried the inner select and I could see exact rows only without AND    ROWNUM <= 2(commented) ...if i use that condition its giving only 2 rows ... I am yet to validate the phone values retrieved for that keycolumn

Comment: @kanagaraj you’ll have to use the analytic row_number function to label the rows in groups then.

Comment: Thanks Boneist , I have verified all my results and its exactly matching with my procedure results .... not sure if I allowed to use this but this works perfectly with single MERGE stmt ...thanks a lot

Comment: Excellent! I take it that it’s performing faster than before? Also, I hope you can see how I got to the merge statement from your procedure? I built up the source subquery first, before adding it into the merge statement (which I chose because you were doing an upsert). The steps are all in the SQL statement.